# Garmin POI Loader

Tags: 13.10

Has anyone loaded the Garmin POI Loader? When I go to their website there are downloads for Windows and Apple, but not for Ubuntu. I have version 13.10 and I am not as good at this stuff as some whose questions and answers I have read and mostly not understood!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. I also have a Garmin device and have struggled to use all its functions in Ubuntu. Garmin only compiles their software for commercial operating systems produced in the US; they want to be sure you buy an operating system licence together with the Garmin device. Contacting Garmin directly would be useful to at least let them know of your problem; don't expect them to solve it though.

Your best chance is to run the POI loader on [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) or [RunOnLinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux). There's no guarantee it will work, but [some folks report](http://www.poi-factory.com/node/15108) they managed with Wine.